# {"Have become" / "Became"} "popular over the past few years?"

Tags: tense

"Reality shows have become very popular over the past few years."
Is it okay to replace "have become" with "became" in this sentence? :)

Answer (score 1):

It would not be incorrect, but the nuances might shift. At least some listeners would expect "became" to be followed by a range of dates -- with the implication that Reality Shows are no longer popular, or that their popularity is waning. "Have become" implies they could still be popular, and is a bit more harmonious to my ears.

This may be my individual "dialect" of American, though.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whatever meaning that you are trying to convey.

The sentence "Reality shows have become very popular over the past few years." indicates that the shows are on the rise starting from "the past few years" and they are still popular/still rising.

The sentence "Reality shows became very popular over the past few years." is grammatically correct; however, it indicates an ambiguity of the popularity of the shows now. The sentence states that the shows have become popular in those "few years" but does not reveal any information about "now." Therefore,  using became can turn the sentence into an indicator of a change in the next sentence.

Answer (score 0):

I find the use of **became** out of place in this sentence.

*Became* is an event verb that describes a single action. The verb itself does not have a sense of duration. Other verbs, *taught*, *read*, *worked* are past verbs that can describe ongoing activities.

The phrase *over the past few years* describes a period of time.

It seems to me that verbs that can be seen as a one-time event, such as "became", do not work so great in the proposed sentence:

?*Reality shows became very popular over the past few years.

?*Germany won the World Cup over the past few years.

?*She went on a diet over the past few years.

?*The man won the lottery over the past few years.

*But consider verbs that express more of of a duration:*

I taught English over the past few years.

The woman read several books over the past few years.

He worked at the TV station over the past few years.

In some of the above, "during the past few years" sounds better than *over the past few years." I suppose it might be up to how one takes "over the past few years", whether it refers to a single time period, such as yesterday, last week, last month, or as indicating an ongoing period of time. If the latter, I don't think *became* works that great.